# Find percentage of color in image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to find the percentage of colors in this image found in Google

```
leaf= imread('https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foglia#/media/File:%C3%89rable_sirop_derable(f)a.jpg');
figure; imshow(leaf);
h = drawpolygon;
bw = createMask(h);
bw = im2uint8(bw);
Masked = bitand(bw,flower);
```

I create a mask to make a smaller ROI and then I plot the histogram of the color channels:

```
[yRed, x] = imhist(Masked(:,:,1));
[yGreen, x] = imhist(Masked(:,:,2));
[yBlue, x] = imhist(Masked(:,:,3));
plot(x, yRed, 'Red', x, yGreen, 'Green', x, yBlue, 'Blue');
```

I'm not sure tho if this implementation is the correct one to get the percentage, of green for example.

```
greenPercentage = 100 * nnz(yGreen) / numel(yGreen)
```

of if there is a better way to extract this information.

Should I create a mask to extract directly the leaf (without the white background)? Because in this case I'm not sure if the percentage is computed correctly

Comment: Few pixels will not have some level of green in them. `nnz(yGreen)` counts all the pixels that don’t have a 0 in the green channel. Only pure black, red, purple or blue will be like that, and you typically won’t find those colors in a photograph. Most colors don’t have 0 green. Do `imshow(yGreen~=0)` to see which pixels are being counted.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Color Thresholder app on the Apps tab of the tool ribbon.

See my Image Segmentation Tutorial in my File Exchange:
[Image Analyst's File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=authorid%3A31862&sort=downloads_desc)
It's a generic, general purpose demo of how to threshold an image to find blobs, and then measure things about the blobs, and extract certain blobs based on their areas or diameters.